# Create a Web Grid using Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

Can we create a WEB GRID dynamically using JAVASCRIPT ?

I am using MVC 3 and Razor as my view.

On one of my Razor view I have a drop down box what I want is to create a web grid dynamically  on selection of a drop down I get the data depending on the value selected from the drop down box.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use ajax for this, where I had called a method using ajax and my method (present in the controller) returned a partial view.

My partial view had the grid I needed to show. and in the method (present in the controller) I had passed value from the dropdown box using ajax, and using this value I had queried my database and sent that model to the partial view.